# How to convert the elements inside the tuple of a list into 2d list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the tuple inside the list and I want to convert all the elements into 2d list. The tuple inside the list is like this

```
 myList=[("[['MDLSBRO', 'TABY'], ['TABY', 'YAAM'], ['YAAM', 'NLRTN'], ['NLRTN', 'THIRSK'], ['THIRSK', 'YORK']]",)]
```

I have no clue how to break this stuff but I want to convert like this any help would be appreciated.

```
 myList=[['MDLSBRO', 'TABY'], ['TABY', 'YAAM'], ['YAAM', 'NLRTN'], ['NLRTN', 'THIRSK'], ['THIRSK', 'YORK']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> myList=[("[['MDLSBRO', 'TABY'], ['TABY', 'YAAM'], ['YAAM', 'NLRTN'], ['NLRTN', 'THIRSK'], ['THIRSK', 'YORK']]",)]
>>> myList = ast.literal_eval(myList[0][0])
>>> myList
[['MDLSBRO', 'TABY'], ['TABY', 'YAAM'], ['YAAM', 'NLRTN'], ['NLRTN', 'THIRSK'], ['THIRSK', 'YORK']]
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) for why you should use this over `eval`.

Comment: what is the advantage of `ast.literal_eval` over builtin `eval`? it worked fine for me

Comment: `eval` tries to implement anything that is inside the string that is passed, this can be especially problematic if you have untrusted code, on the other hand, `ast.literal_eval` will only evaluate if the element inside the string is a valid python data structure.